# CORS Policy Error when attempting to POST to Twilio API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twilio

From a VueJS application I'm attempting to do a simple POST to the Twilio API in order to send an SMS. When the POST is executed I receive the following error:

```
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC42exxxxxxxxxxcfa9c48/SMS/Messages' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field username is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."
```

The offending code is the following:

```
sendTwilio(){
    const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
    const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
    const sFromNumber = process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER;
    const sBaseURL = 'https://api.twilio.com';
    const phoneNumber = parsePhoneNumberFromString(this.sms.to_number,'US') 

    const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    'username': `${accountSid}`
    },

    sBodyText='Test'

    this.SmsUrl = sBaseURL + '/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + accountSid + '/SMS/Messages';

    if (phoneNumber.isValid()){
        this.sms.formattedPhone = phoneNumber.number;

        this.postData = 'From=' + sFromNumber 
        + '+To=' + phoneNumber.number 
        + '+Body=' + sBodyText

        axios.post(`${this.SmsUrl}`, this.postData, {
            headers: headers
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)   
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)   
        })                    
    }
},
```

Is the problem with the format used for the username in the header or something with my CORS settings?

My CORS settings are as follows:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [        
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'http://localhost:8080',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
]
```

Comment: Twilio’s API is rejecting the `username` header on your request - are you sure you need to add that header? If so, can you post the documentation for that endpoint that shows that header is required?

Comment: wait, why/how are you doing an `XMLHttpRequest` if you are in nodejs? 
CORS issues should/can only arise in the browser. i hope you're not exposing your twilio credentials in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio uses [Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to do authentication, so in your case when doing your `POST` using `axios` you need to do:

```
const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
const auth = {
    username: accountSid,
    password: authToken
}
[...]
axios.post(this.SmsUrl, this.postData, {
    auth: auth,
    headers: headers
})
```

I'm not sure how you're using this though. Have a look at the comments of the question. You should never expose your Twilio credentials to the client in a browser application.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  That seems to have solved that issue. (of course, nowTwilio doesn't seem to recognize the 'to' phone number but that's an issue I'll wrestle with later on..)  As far as the issue with exposing my Twilio credentials, yes that is true but I was only, at this time, simply trying to test the ability to connect and receive a response.  Thanks!